Can't turn on Network Discovery on Windows Server 2016 VM
I am experimenting with a VM and want to share a folder from my main PC to my VM (Win Server 2016 set up as a domain - main is NOT in the domain)
When I go to network and sharing - I see that Network discovery is turned off (which is why I'm assuming I cant ping the Server)
However, when I select turn on and save changes.  I go back into the settings and its still off.
Can someone point me in the right direction here?

You will have to share more information about the VM. Network Discovery being disabled wouldn't prevent you from being able to ping the host from within the VM or the VM from the host. My guess you have a misconfigured physical and/or virtual network adapter

Thanks for the reply.  Running an ipconfig they seem to be on the same network and gateway.  Like the VM is 10.0.0.100 and the other PC is 10.0.0.41

Another thing I noticed is that the VM CAN ping a different computer on the network but not the PC running the VM.  And it doesnt time out it says 'Destination Host Unreachable'.  I also CAN ping the 0.0.0.41 from a different machine on the network.  So its only this VM I cant ping from

That doesn’t tell me anything about the physical or virtual network adapter

In Hyper-V the Virtual Switch is ticked [x] External Netowork with my Intel Ethernet Controller selected. and checked [Allow management operating system to share this network adapter].  Within the VM its configured as a static IP.  The ethernet adapater on main PC is configured as DHCP

Why is none of that information in your question?

Deleting the virtual switch and re-creating it fixed the problem.
